# How to make a thread with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc application with html and angular in the client side, I have a method in my controller angular that i want to run every 5 seconds, how to do that with angular ?
thank u for your help
this is my code

```
$scope.inspectionEnCoursDinspection=[];          
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/projet/getInspectionEnCoursDinspection").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

     $scope.inspectionEnCoursDinspection1=data;
}),
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Wrap your code in $interval. Here is an example https://plnkr.co/edit/UYEyszI0s2tI9rt7kFLf?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your desired code in an $interval and set it to run based on the interval time you choose:

Ex using 100ms interval:

```
$interval(function() {
        if ($scope.blood_1 > 0 && $scope.blood_2 > 0) {
          $scope.blood_1 = $scope.blood_1 - 3;
          $scope.blood_2 = $scope.blood_2 - 4;
        } else {
          $scope.stopFight();
        }
      }, 100);
```

With further docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval